# How to make sure a route is called only after completing payment on Stripe?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, stripe-payments

I have configured stripe on my website successfully. But as soon as they make the payment, I have an HTTP route that updates their 'pro' status in my MongoDB database. But the problem I am facing is that I call the 'fetch' call in the client is called as soon as they click pay now and the user is updated in the database without finishing the payment.

Another problem of me updating the user like this is that anyone will be able to share this HTTP route and upgrade their account to pro. Here are the code snippets:

Server Route:

```
app.patch('/new-pro', async(req,res)=>{
try{
    const email = req.query.email
    console.log(email)
    const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate({email:email}, { $set: {pro: 'true'}}, {new:true})
    
    res.send(user)
}catch(e){

}
})
```

Client:

```
var checkoutButton = document.getElementById('checkout-button');
var inputEmail = document.getElementById('accountEmail')
var paymentForm = document.getElementById('paymentForm')




paymentForm.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    const email = inputEmail.value
    console.log(email)
    fetch("/charge").then((response) => {
        response.json().then((data) => {
            console.log(data.id)
            // stripe.redirectToCheckout({
            //     sessionId:
            // }).then(function (result) {
            //     // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
            //     // error, display the localized error message to your customer
            //     // using `result.error.message`.
            // });
            stripe.redirectToCheckout({
                sessionId: data.id
            }).then((result) => {

            })
            fetch('/new-pro?email=' + encodeURIComponent(email), { method: 'PATCH' }).then((a) => {
                console.log('here')
            })


        })

    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
        console.log('yo')
    })
```

Any way I can address these 2 issues.

Comment: Generally you need to register a callback with the payment processor.

Comment: Can you please expand on that. Sorry, I am very new to all this.  Do you have any idea how to do that with Stripe in particular? Thanks for that though, I will try and find it in the docs.

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks

Comment: Thank you very much. That helps a lot. I was also looking into web sockets in general.